# How would one pass a value, through a form using POST, by clicking on a picture?

Tags: php, html

As a personal project and learning exercise I created a personal "new tab" page (http://bionboy.github.io/newt-ab/).

I have since progressed in my learning and am currently teaching myself **PHP**. I would like to create a PHP form that logs what link I click so that I can see what links I use the most.

I am specifically having trouble passing a value with the pictures on my site and was wondering how I could do such a thing without editing the appearance.

So far I have decided that I will submit the value of the link clicked and then use the header() function in **PHP** to redirect to the desired website.

PS: I am also using **JavaScript** and **Jquery** on the site.

PS: I could potentially host this site on my personal server if that helps.

Comment: what you want to achieve?? you want to log any link within your page clicked to be logged or what?

Comment: add some data attribute (ex. data-id="5") image bind click event in jquery and send ajax post request where you identify item you clicked

Answer (score 0):

You can set value in attribute of picture then get it after click
using javascript or jquery and send POST request with value.

```
var value = $('#picture_id').attr('attribute_name');
$.ajax({
    //...
    data: {value: value},
    dataType: 'json',
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **that Picture** in a `submit` button.

```css
.img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("data:image/jpeg;base64,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");
  
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="text" name="user"/>
<input type="submit" class="img" value=""/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the other posts, I have solved my problem.
What I did was change my link elements from

This:`<a class="icon" href="https://mail.google.com/mail"><img id='gmail' src="icons/gmail-icon.png"></a>`

To this:`<input type="image" alt="submit" name="submit" value="gmail" class="icon" id='gmail' src="icons/gmail-icon.png" />`.

After that I had to enclose those elements into the following form element:`<form action="form.php" method="POST"></form>`

Then in my PHP I logged the value of $_POST['submit'] into a file and then setup a switch statement that redirected to the desired site using the PHP function header().